# Can't view pics/vids when opening an HTML

Tags: video, images, html

When opening a local HTML file on my android device, the local files i.e videos and pictures don't show up. The HTML file works great but the local pictures and videos don't load. Is there any solution to this problem? I tried different browsers, but the problem keep coming.

Note: I don't get an access denied error, the page load normally, but the pictures/videos don't.

For reference my mobile is at Android 13 with OneUI 5.1